# PopViewController has no effect

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

I'm new to iOS programming and I'm spending way too much time on something that is supposed to be relatively easy to implement. Surely this is a beginner's question, but I just can't seem to find an answer.

I'm currently developing an iOS VoIP app. At this stage the system will switch to a "CallingViewController" whenever a call is set up. Whenever the call is disconnected the view should disappear (pop).

My hierarchy:

- Window

  - navigationController : UINavigationController (window.rootViewController)

    - AppController : UIViewController (navigationController.rootView)

      - TabBarController : UITabBarController

        - DialerViewController : UIViewController
      - LoginViewController : UIViewController
      - CallingViewController : UIViewController

I imagined AppController to be the class which loads and hides views based on states and events being triggered by all the VoIP related coding.

For instance in the AppController I use  `[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];` . Pushing a controller does not seem to cause any problems, everything functions as expected.

Pushing tabBarController causes DialerView to get focus (it is for now the only view in te tab, later it will for instance contain: Dialer, Settings, Contacts, Call History). The user enters a number and presses "VoIP Call". Via callbacks (voiplibrary->OnCallStateChange -> eventually AppController.OnCallStateChange) the system can determine the state of Call (callId) has changed to "SET UP" and will push (in AppController)  `[self.navigationController pushViewController:CallingViewController animated:YES];` .

Through the same callback function the system will also determine that the call had ended. Yet, using popViewController or any variant, it does not  work. The ViewController stays on top. I started logging using NSLog and it appears the CallingView: loads, willappear, didappear and willdisappear. DidDisappear will not get called however. The system also did determine the call was terminated, checked via NSLog again. So whatever code I use to get rid of the CallingViewController will get executed (it seems), however the View does not change.

Comment: So after a day of stumbling I actually found the answer a good half an hour after I posted my question. 

The VoIP library uses callbacks which get called from a different thread other than the main thread. When using  <code>performOnMainThread->popController</code> function I can actually pop the controller of the stack. Et voila! 

However calling <code>pushViewController</code> from a different thread actually does work. Could anyone elaborate on this?

Comment: Simply said, any change to the UI has to be done on the main (UI) thread. Not doing so, as you can see, will result in unexpected behaviour or even crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say if that is the cause for your problem but as per documentation

for

```
pushViewController:animated:
```

method

> This object cannot be an instance of tab bar controller and it must not already be on the navigation stack.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I only push TabBarController. Whichever view has focus 'in there' is up to the TabBarController. This behaviour (last opened) is intended. If I understand correctly, what you described is not the case. Eitherway I learned something :)

Comment: I understand, still you are **pushing** an instance of tabbarcontroller onto the uinavigationcontroller stack which is not advised. Even if it works for you now, it might create trouble for you at some point.

Comment: Is there any advice you can give me on how to tackle this situation then? Basically my app will have <Dialer,Settings,Contact,History> in a TabBarController, this represents the main app. And a few screens which need to get focus on certain events <IncomingCall, Calling, Login>

Comment: Personally, I don't think you need the uinavigationcontroller at all, that should be used to provide the user with the sense of hierarchy. Your app doesn't have that. Login and calling views are both views that interrupt regular flow of the app and therefore presentation should resamble "modal" type of action.

Comment: That sounds very logical, thank you very much! I'm developing my app as part of an internship and with time pressing and me being very new to iOS I figured the navigation stack would be the easy route (for user's sense and easy app flow). Thanks to your comment I realised I might aswell display a navigationBar without using the stack, should I need one. I'll study up!